# Material-UI dependencies: ''react-tap-event-plugin'' has no exported member 'injectTapEventPlugin'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings

I'm working with react/typescript/material-ui/webpack. Material-UI has a dependency to `react-tap-event-plugin` and I am having issues importing the injectTapEventPlugin function, here is the error I got:

```
error TS2305: Module ''react-tap-event-plugin'' has no exported member 'injectTapEventPlugin'.
```

To add the definition for `react-tap-event-plugin` I used the following command:

```
sudo typings install dt~react-tap-event-plugin --save --global --save-dev
```

The index.d.ts looks like this:

```
declare module 'react-tap-event-plugin'{
    interface StrategyOverrides {
         shouldRejectClick?: (lastTouchEventTimestamp: Date, clickEventTimestamp: Date) => boolean;
    }

    var injectTapEventPlugin: (strategyOverrides?: StrategyOverrides) => void;

    export = injectTapEventPlugin;
}
```

I am trying to import the plugin in my App using:

```
import {injectTapEventPlugin} from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Any idea on what I am missing?

Comment: try this `import injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");`

Comment: It's working ! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the test file in the github project

```
// since the export is a function, this is the only actual correct way:
import injectTapEventPluginRequire = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react-tap-event-plugin/react-tap-event-plugin-tests.ts

Comment: I get the following error: error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 6 modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.

Comment: Maybe for someone who want to use this feature here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11689 mentioned `Remove support for TapEventPlugin`

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting ES6 and you are trying to solve this with the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37918986/95008) you might get the following typescript warning/error:

> "Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 6 modules. Consider using `import * as ns from "mod"`, `import {a} from "mod"`, or another module format instead.

-as already @thomas-jespersen has commented on for the solution.

The error message is giving some suggestions on ways to work around this, but I couldn't get none of them to work - "out of the box" as suggested. I did however get it working by doing this (which probably can be even more refined):

`...
import * as injectTapEventPluginExport from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
const injectTapEventPlugin = (injectTapEventPluginExport as any).default;
injectTapEventPlugin();
...`

It doesn't look pretty, but it does seem to work.

I have a feeling that erratic or outdated typescript definitions for the `inject-tap-event-plugin` is the real cause of this though.